# The Walker? Set In the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story a number of years ago. I'm pretty sure the title was "The Walker". I think it was near the end of an anthology of other short stories.

I remember most of the story, but not the book it was in.

It was set in a future city where EVERYTHING was automated. The people all lived on/in pod type things that provided nutrition and got rid of waste. They were totally dedicated to experience and experimentation. No one walked and the pods moved them everywhere. The main character saw a man walking on the ground and decided to talk to him. They had many conversations and the pod man decided to try standing. His pod kept asking him if he wanted help. Then, he decided to try walking. He started noticing things like strange noises at night and people missing the next day. One day, he decided to walk out of the city to find the man he had been talking to. He did. When he looked back at the city, he could see that the bottom was in bad shape; new had been built on top of the old and it was all starting to fall apart.

I know there were other good stories in the book and would like to read them again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Coming in at tale number 99 of [100 Twisted Little Tales of Torment](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47), we have *The Walker* by Donald R. Burleson, could this be it?

Comment: Could you please summarize "The Walker" and how it matches the points in the question?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I could find... the story title near the end of a collection.

Comment: It's a possibility, but I don't seem to remember there being quite that many stories in the book